# Inaccurate New User Query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT( uid ) AS `Records` , DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( 'since` ) ) AS `Date`
    FROM `accounts` WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME(since) >= FROM_UNIXTIME($tstamp) 
    GROUP BY WEEK( FROM_UNIXTIME( `since` ) )
    LIMIT 200
```

Was using this to try to get the New user signups daily from a specified date but its turning out to be incredibly inaccurate. Which means either my query is off or possibly there is some issue involving timezones?Below is a example result I got from a example data set I loaded in as well as a page worth of timestamps so you can see what the results should be.

[image: Result Sample]

[image: Actual DB READABLE TSTAMPS]

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` with `GROUP BY` clause.
Also the backtick(`) operator is not used properly in this code.

So change this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( uid ) AS Records , DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( 'since` ) ) AS `Date`
    FROM `accounts` WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME(since) >= FROM_UNIXTIME($tstamp) 
    GROUP BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `since` ) )
    LIMIT 200
```

to this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(`uid`) AS Records , DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME(`since`) ) AS Date
    FROM accounts
    GROUP BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `since` ) )
    HAVING FROM_UNIXTIME(`since`) >= FROM_UNIXTIME($tstamp)
    LIMIT 200
```